# Pretty faces simple mapping

Tags: prettyfaces

I followed this simple tutorial on http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/ with a simple mapping in pretty-config.xml but when I hit **index** mapping I get 404. Bellow the pretty-config.xml

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                      http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">

    <rewrite match="^/(.*)/$" substitute="/$1" redirect="301" />

    <url-mapping id="index">
        <pattern value="/index" />
        <view-id value="/index.xhtml" />
    </url-mapping>

</pretty-config>
```

I'm using JSF 2.1, Primefaces 3.5 and Prettyfaces 2.0.5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PrettyFaces 2.0.5 is VERY old! You should update to 3.3.3 and try again.

Comment: And you you also show your FacesServlet mapping?

Comment: Thanks chkal, it works after upgrading to 3.3.3!

Comment: Glad to hear it is working for you now.